# How to create multiple web application (different website) with 1 laravel installation

Tags: laravel, multiple-instances

Requirement - I need to create 5 web applications for 5 different websites.

Current Status - I have created 1 web application in laravel.

### Query - How to use this laravel instance to code for other 4 web applications.

I am sorry if the question is not clear, or if I am not using the right terms here.
I have 5 websites -www.sample1.com through www.sample5.com. Application related to www.sample1.com is already done in laravel with its own database and logics. Now, I want to create a similar application for www.sample2 through www.sample5.com. Do I need to download and create 4 seperate laravel projects for the 4 websites?

Comment: Do you mean save application but with different domains and database?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is not clear, or if I am not using the right terms here. I have 5 websites -www.sample1.com through www.sample5.com. Application related to www.sample1.com is already done in laravel with its own database and logics. Now, I want to create a similar application for www.sample2 through www.sample5.com. Do I need to download and create 4 seperate laravel projects for the 4 websites >

Comment: That's fine but please answer my question, then perhaps I can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a new Laravel Instance for each website.
This allows you to use artisan for all the works and not bother about server change of one of your projects. The size of a Laravel installation is negliable.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this means, new laravel instance for each application. ANd in this particular example, there would be 5 laravel instances each having its sub-folders like app/model/public etc.

Comment: Jup, exactly! It's a nice and easy workflow